# Extracting a submatrix with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

In a package of mine, I extract a submatrix `B` from a matrix `A` as follows:

```cpp
NumericMatrix extractColumns(NumericMatrix A, IntegerVector indices) {
  int n = indices.size();
  int m = A.nrow();
  NumericMatrix B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B(_, i) = A(_, indices(i));
  }
  return B;
}
```

I observed it is slow. Then I've just benchmarked and this is indeed slower than the ordinary R way:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix extractColumns(NumericMatrix A, IntegerVector indices) {
  int n = indices.size();
  int m = A.nrow();
  NumericMatrix B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B(_, i) = A(_, indices(i));
  }
  return B;
}

//

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 2L, ncol = 50000L)
indices <- 2000L:40000L 
microbenchmark(
  R    = A[, indices],
  Rcpp = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
  times = 5L
)
*/
```

Why is it slow and is there a faster way with **Rcpp**? (the indices are not contiguous in general).

---

## Edit

Also tested with **RcppEigen**. Slow as well.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd extractColumns2(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Rcpp::IntegerVector indices) {
  int m = A.rows();
  int n = indices.size();
  Eigen::MatrixXd B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B.col(i) = A.col(indices(i));
  }
  return B;
}
```

Comment: I suspect there is something in Armadillo making this easy and efficient. Otherwise, maybe drop the dimension attribute, subset the underlying vector and add a dimension attribute.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. I don't want to use Armadillo. I already include **RcppEigen** and other libraries. How would you subset the underlying vector?

Comment: Each indexing call is a function call with small overhead.  If you do many, it may add up.  (Dense) matrices and vector _are_ contiguous so if you are truly motivated and need the speed youi can do the 'basic pointer plus offset' indexing yourself and save some time.  Without looking it up, this is surely what R does.  These days we also have `collapse` and other projects.  I would use `RcppArmadillo` and I note that other CRAN depend on both `RcppEigen` and `RcppArmadillo`.  We offer (some) convenience at (some) cost, the rest are all your tradeoffs. Maybe profile some more?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ; [armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) has  subsetting with a non-contiguous  vector of indices, also there is https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html but
the good folks at [RcppEigen](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/issues/103) are still working towards Eigen 3.4. **edit** sorry just noticed your comment re armadillo

Comment: The good folks at RcppEigen wave a hand and can state that is very stale for lack of help: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/issues/103  This hasn't moved in some time.  Help always welcome!

Comment: I also keep think that for your CGAL meshes (which, as I understand it, are always 3 x N) you may have a possibility to do this 'more indirectly' with pointer incements.  Then again it is probably also possible to take advantage of column wise operations if you tranpose.  But of that amortises the const of tranposing (twice?) is unclear _ex ante_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel CGAL meshes are `arbitrary x N` (but to plot them with **rgl** we need `3/4 x N`). Actually there were two sources of slowness in my code. The one exposed here, and an `apply` on a large matrix (the faces of the mesh). Now I do the matrix extraction in R (but I still calculate the indices with **Rcpp**) and I do the `apply` in **Rcpp**. Very fast now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and worth comparing a few approaches.  I also think it is worth reiterating that we almost always have a tradeoff between clarity and performance.  As such, I still like RcppArmadillo (even though the second measurement set below looks a little worrisome).

First off, the code. I added a function for RcppArmadillo which, given a vector of *unsigned* indices, can index directly which makes it a one-liner. Which clearly wins on clarity.

##### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix extractColumns(Rcpp::NumericMatrix A, Rcpp::IntegerVector indices) {
  int n = indices.size();
  int m = A.nrow();
  NumericMatrix B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B(_, i) = A(_, indices(i));
  }
  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix extractColumns1(NumericMatrix A, IntegerVector indices) {
  int n = indices.size();
  int m = A.nrow();
  NumericMatrix B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      B(i, j) = A(i, indices(j));
    }
  }
  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd extractColumns2(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Rcpp::IntegerVector indices) {
  int m = A.rows();
  int n = indices.size();
  Eigen::MatrixXd B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B.col(i) = A.col(indices(i));
  }
  return B;
}

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat extractColumns3(arma::mat A, arma::uvec v) {
    return A.cols(v);
}
```

##### Benchmark

I made two changes. First, I added `collapse` besides (Rcpp)Armadillo as it explicitly aims for performance (for the R user) which efficient and pure code.  Second, because the original matrix was a bit degenerate with two rows times 50k colums, I create a somewhat more balanced 200 by 500 one.

```
/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 2L, ncol = 50000L)
indices <- 2000L:40000L
microbenchmark(
  R         = A[, indices],
  RcppBasic = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppImprv = extractColumns1(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppEigen = extractColumns2(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppArma  = extractColumns3(A, indices - 1L),
  collapse  = collapse::ss(A, 1:2, indices),
  times = 25L
)

A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 200L, ncol = 500L)
indices <- 200L:400L
microbenchmark(
  R         = A[, indices],
  RcppBasic = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppImprv = extractColumns1(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppEigen = extractColumns2(A, indices - 1L),
  RcppArma  = extractColumns3(A, indices - 1L),
  collapse  = collapse::ss(A, 1:200, indices),
  times = 25L
)

all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns(A, indices - 1L))
all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns2(A, indices - 1L))
all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns3(A, indices - 1L))
all.equal(A[, indices], collapse::ss(A, 1:200, indices))

*/
```

##### Results

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/76538309/question.cpp")

> library(microbenchmark)

> A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 2L, ncol = 50000L)

> indices <- 2000L:40000L

> microbenchmark(
+ >   R         = A[, indices],
+ >   RcppBasic = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
+ >   RcppImprv = extractColumns1(A, indices - 1L),
+ >   .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
         R  198.698  201.356  601.502  247.764  406.431 4636.895    25 ab 
 RcppBasic 1260.979 1337.403 1742.815 1522.285 1789.843 4884.915    25   c
 RcppImprv  310.913  339.943  623.045  533.361  587.319 2480.557    25 ab 
 RcppEigen  293.941  502.759  922.591  772.874 1024.857 4161.447    25 a  
  RcppArma  299.430  330.409  811.221  786.544 1072.527 1997.107    25 ab 
  collapse  201.500  210.785  316.888  327.262  409.214  465.755    25  b 

> A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 200L, ncol = 500L)

> indices <- 200L:400L

> microbenchmark(
+ >   R         = A[, indices],
+ >   RcppBasic = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
+ >   RcppImprv = extractColumns1(A, indices - 1L),
+ >   .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: microseconds
      expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval cld
         R  63.524  64.036  80.8516  65.433  72.149  174.069    25   a
 RcppBasic  23.706  27.381  70.9232  31.737 135.762  144.999    25   a
 RcppImprv 132.711 134.079 151.1988 136.953 139.232  250.357    25   a
 RcppEigen  51.693  75.133 172.8276 121.080 163.501  434.985    25   a
  RcppArma  79.163  95.515 290.6080 187.556 515.465  618.522    25   a
  collapse  65.720  66.837 240.1691  68.680  95.058 3777.815    25   a

> all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns(A, indices - 1L))
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns1(A, indices - 1L))
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns2(A, indices - 1L))
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(A[, indices], extractColumns3(A, indices - 1L))
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(A[, indices], collapse::ss(A, 1:200, indices))
[1] TRUE
>
```

##### Comment

Lots of things matter. The 'improved Rcpp' function by @Mikko looks good on the original "and oddly shaped matrix", it underperforms vis-a-vis the Rcpp Sugar enhanced one ... because Sugar can give you parallel loop unrolling which starts to matter once there is looping to be done (and hurts when not as seen here).  The 'collapse' function looks and beats base R on the
"odd" matrix and is at par on the normal one. Eigen and Armadillo do their thing, on the "odd" matrix they suffer (and using them forces casts that have a small cost).  The bad performance of RcppArmadillo on the second example is a bit of head-scratcher.

So in sum: Details matter. The setup matters.  Nothing really dominates all use cases.

Comment: It seems that **Eigen 3.4.90** supports submatrix views ([here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html)). It would be good to include this feature in the `RcppEigen` package.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's at least some overhead associated with the `_` sugar. I noticed that writing out the inner loop explicitly makes things a bit faster, but still a bit off the native R method:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix extractColumns(NumericMatrix A, IntegerVector indices) {
  int n = indices.size();
  int m = A.nrow();
  NumericMatrix B(m, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      B(i, j) = A(i, indices(j));
    }
  }
  return B;
}

//

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 2L, ncol = 50000L)
indices <- 2000L:40000L 
microbenchmark(
  R    = A[, indices],
  Rcpp = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
  times = 5L
)
*/
```

```r
> library(microbenchmark)
> A <- matrix(rgamma(100000L, 5, 1), nrow = 2L, ncol = 50000L)
> indices <- 2000L:40000L 
> microbenchmark(
+   R    = A[, indices],
+   Rcpp = extractColumns(A, indices - 1L),
+   times = 5L
+ )
Unit: microseconds
 expr   min    lq   mean median    uq    max neval cld
    R 325.5 367.2 393.72  382.3 422.5  471.1     5   a
 Rcpp 366.6 370.9 788.70  431.1 597.8 2177.1     5   a
```